# upload handle change list antd keep loading

Tags: reactjs, antd

i got a project from other team.the promblem is upload file and image using antd.everything working well but when come to upload pdf file the progress bar keep loading forever but when i click submit the pdf uploaded to the server so i think the handle change was the problem

[here the pdf upload loading forever picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQlhm.png)

and when i try to upload image the text turn red but submit working as well

[here example of image upload the text get red like error but submit working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy8XA.png)

here the error message when i inspect element
[error from inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx9Tk.jpg)

here image edit code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Card,
  Space,
  Typography,
  Button,
  Tooltip,
  Avatar,
  Upload,
  message,
} from 'antd';

import { InfoOutlined, UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

import CustomTitle from '@components/Title';

import { KAJIAN_DAN_KONSULTASI } from '@constants/urls';
import fetchRequest, { fetchFormData } from '@utils/fetcher';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

const { Title } = Typography;

const EditMainPictureConsultation = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState('');
  const [mediaUrl, setMediaUrl] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleImageUpload = async (info: any) => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];
    fileList = fileList.slice(-1);

    fileList = fileList.map((file) => {
      if (file.response) {
        file.url = file.response.url;
      }
      return file;
    });

    setMediaUrl(fileList);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    if (mediaUrl) {
      formData.append('file', mediaUrl[0]?.originFileObj || mediaUrl[0]?.url);
    }

    try {
      await fetchFormData({
        method: 'POST',
        path: 'resource/service/study-and-consul/main-picture',
        data: formData,
      }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.error) {
          navigate(KAJIAN_DAN_KONSULTASI);
        } else {
          message.error(response.error.message);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      message.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const getPictureData = async (id: string) => {
    try {
      await fetchRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'resource?id=' + id,
      }).then((response) => {
        setMediaUrl([
          {
            uid: '-1',
            name: 'mainPictureConsultation.png',
            status: 'done',
            url: response.url,
          },
        ]);
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const isEdit =
      location.pathname.split('/').filter((pn) => pn === 'edit').length > 0;

    if (isEdit) {
      const path = location.pathname.split('/');
      const pictId = path[path.indexOf('edit') + 1];

      setId(pictId);
      getPictureData(pictId);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col span={12} offset={6}>
        <Card>
          <Space direction="vertical" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <Space align="baseline">
              <CustomTitle name="Gambar Konsultasi" url={KAJIAN_DAN_KONSULTASI} />
              <Tooltip title="Menerima jenis file: .jpg, .jpeg, .png. Untuk icon transparan gunakan .png">
                <Avatar
                  size={'small'}
                  icon={<InfoOutlined />}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: '#8C8C8C' }}
                ></Avatar>
              </Tooltip>
            </Space>
            <Title level={5}>Gambar</Title>
            <Upload
              listType="picture"
              maxCount={1}
              accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"
              fileList={mediaUrl}
              onChange={handleImageUpload}
            >
              <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Unggah Icon</Button>
            </Upload>
            <Row justify="end">
              <Col>
                <Button type="primary" danger onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>
                  Simpan Perubahan
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Space>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default EditMainPictureConsultation;
```

here's the edit pdf code

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Card,
  Space,
  Typography,
  Button,
  message,
  Avatar,
  Tooltip,
  Upload,
} from 'antd';

import { UploadOutlined, InfoOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

import CustomTitle from '@components/Title';

import { PELATIHAN } from '@constants/urls';

import { fetchFormData } from '@utils/fetcher';

const { Title } = Typography;

const EditCatalogTraining = () => {
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleFileUpload = async (info: any) => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];
    fileList = fileList.slice(-1);

    fileList = fileList.map((file) => {
      if (file.response) {
        file.url = file.response.url;
      }
      return file;
    });

    setFileUrl(fileList);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    if (fileUrl) {
      formData.append('file', fileUrl[0]?.originFileObj || fileUrl[0]?.url);
    }

    try {
      await fetchFormData({
        method: 'POST',
        path: 'resource/service/training/catalog',
        data: formData,
      }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.error) {
          navigate(PELATIHAN);
        } else {
          if (Array.isArray(response.message)) {
            response.message.map((msg: string) => message.error(msg));
          } else {
            message.error(response.message);
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      message.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col span={12} offset={6}>
        <Card>
          <Space direction="vertical" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <Space align="baseline">
              <CustomTitle name="Katalog Layanan" url={PELATIHAN} />
              <Tooltip title="Menerima jenis file: .pdf. Unggah sertifikat dalam bentuk file .pdf maksimal 25mb.">
                <Avatar
                  size={'small'}
                  icon={<InfoOutlined />}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: '#8C8C8C' }}
                ></Avatar>
              </Tooltip>
            </Space>
            <Title level={5}>Katalog</Title>
            <Upload
              listType="picture"
              maxCount={1}
              accept=".pdf"
              fileList={fileUrl}
               onChange={handleFileUpload}
            >
              <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Unggah Katalog</Button>
            </Upload>
            <Row justify="end">
              <Col>
                <Button type="primary" danger onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>
                  Simpan Perubahan
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Space>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default EditCatalogTraining;
```

please help me with the handle change list how to turn to how its suppose to.submit work well the data upload to the server.

Comment: I don't know if I understood right... you want to upload a pdf/img when you select the file (or drop it on upload component) or you want to upload it when you submited the form?

Comment: @NoNam4 after i select the file.the progress keep loading or change to red like the in the picture.but when i submitted the form while its keep loading the file uploaded to server

Comment: As you want to upload your file to server when you selected the file you should set `action` URL in upload component, also in `beforeUpload` event you should return true. If you return false the server upload will be aborted but you'll still be able to upload on form submit. You should take a look into antd [docs](https://ant.design/components/upload#api)

Comment: @NoNam4 sorry but how to set the action URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following script,
When uploading, Antd will immediately execute the action function, you have to handle the action so that the return is always 200

```
 const props: UploadProps = {
    onRemove: (file) => {
      const index = fileList.indexOf(file);
      const newFileList = fileList.slice();
      newFileList.splice(index, 1);
      setFileList(newFileList);
    },
    beforeUpload: (file) => {
      setFileList([file]);
      const isJpgOrPng =
        file.type === "image/jpeg" ||
        file.type === "image/png" ||
        file.type === "image/jpg" ||
        file.type === "application/pdf";
      if (!isJpgOrPng) {
        message.error("You can only upload JPG/PNG file!");
        const index = fileList.indexOf(file);
        const newFileList = fileList.slice();
        newFileList.splice(index, 1);
        setFileList(newFileList);
      }
      const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
      if (!isLt2M) {
        message.error("Image must smaller than 2MB!");
        const index = fileList.indexOf(file);
        const newFileList = fileList.slice();
        newFileList.splice(index, 1);
        setFileList(newFileList);
      }
      return isJpgOrPng && isLt2M;
    },
    fileList,
    action: "/api",
    accept: "image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg. application/pdf",
    maxCount: 1,
  };


<Upload {...props}>
     <Button>Select File</Button>
 </Upload>
```

for api you can custom url always return 200

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  return new Response("noop", {
    status: 200,
  });
}
```

then you can still use the handleSubmit function